# Using Wordpress pages as Drupal 7's "basic page" type of content

Tags: wordpress, drupal

Drupal 7 divides content in two types:

> **Article**
>
> Use articles for time-sensitive
>   content like news, press releases or
>   blog posts.
>
> **Basic page**
>
> Use basic pages for your static
>   content, such as an 'About us' page.

Then, that content can be inserted into blocks (located in the header, content, footer etc.)

I wonder if I can get the same result by using Wordpress **Pages** as Drupal's **Basic pages** with the `get_pages` function.

So one Page will have many "child pages" displaying content in different blocks within the parent page.

Because right now, I'm using "Posts" filtered as "Categories" in order  generate editable static content.

Which one is the best way to go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress Pages are designed -- much like Drupal's Basic Page -- for static information. wp_list_pages(); (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_pages) displays a list of pages as links in a tree, get_pages displays pages not as a tree.

I don't know because I'm not sure what theme you're using, but it probably wouldn't be too hard to write a widget that displays info from pages. You can really use either pages or posts, it doesn't matter too much. The convention is to use Pages for static content -- see: http://en.support.wordpress.com/post-vs-page/